# Force a browser to download an BIG HTML file to disk and open it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, web

**Task:** 
I have a huge html file that is placed on server, I want to show it to the user by click of an URL.

**Issue:**
As this file is huge, On click of the URL the browser doesn't render the page in time*(Records get appended continuously  while the vertical scroll bar size diminishes, user is not able to do anything but see the first few records)* and the default spinner of the browser spins endlessly.

---

Can this be achieve this way, if yes, how?---> On click of the "link", the html file should get downloaded on client machine first, then viewed on client browser window from his local system not from URL directly(maybe in a iframe or something).

**EDIT**
loading 500 MB of HTML was asking a lot of a browser.

**Work around**
Since generated htmls files were huge, we converted htmls files to pdf format. Later, used browser's default pdf viewer capability to view the data on browser window itself or simply downloaded the pdf file onto the disk.

Comment: Does the HTML file needs to run some JS or links any CSS file OR do you only care about the HTML markup?

Comment: only plan old html nothing else. but the size is huge.. in 500MBs etc

Comment: *"we converted htmls files to pdf format(500 MB reduced to 5 MB, 100 times smaller)"*... How it that possible? I'm pretty sure your HTML document is somehow **extremely** messed up. oO

Comment: it was not exactly 500MB but of that order.. htmls were generated through a tool. but we found that the pdf equivalent were of the order of few MBs. Also, removed that line from my comments to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to force a browser to download an HTML file to disk and open it.

In practical terms, a 500+ MB HTML file will never be readable -- loading it requires much more memory than is available to a web browser. Downloading it won't help. You need to break it up into smaller documents.

Comment: can we use any lazy loading strategy? Or can we put a limit on how much data can be rendered, as in one chuck that holds good for all browsers?

Comment: Unlikely. It won't perform well no matter what -- loading 500 MB of HTML is asking a lot of a browser, even if none of it is rendered.

Comment: Ok, last note, the best possible way would be to generate a pdf and show? coz I noticed that pdf file generated for this html is in few MBs. How would you possible approach this problem if this were given to you, how should I go about breaking up in small document and make the user see the entire report?

Comment: A PDF seems unlikely to be better unless there is something very strange about your HTML. I would expect 500 MB of HTML to generate a PDF that's tens of thousands of pages long, if not longer.

Comment: This change in file format turned out to be cool option for the most part [I had also, limited the number of pages to around 3k page, solution worked for most browsers] HOWEVER, after much testing I found that on chrome version 54 and below, on submission to a pdf url, it does not display pdf on browser window, instead pdf gets downloaded to local machine:(

Answer (score 0):

Split it into chunks. If there's not too much code in the file, you could use something like 'split -l 7500 filename'. By default, the web browser should be able to fix html tags that dont have a specified end. If you dont need to render it, open it in a text editor designed for large files, as it wont try to load the whole thing in one go.